# Simplify zipWith and case using LambdaCase

Tags: haskell, lambda, pattern-matching, zipwith

With the following zipWith expression:

```hs
zipWith3 (\foos bars bazs -> case (foos, bars, bazs) of
    (foo, bar, Just baz)  -> Right "hell yeah"
    (foo, bar, Nothing) -> Left "tough luck"
) ["foo1", "foo2"] ["bar1", "bar2"] [Just "baz1", Just "baz2"]
```

Is it possible to use `LambdaCase` to simplify the `case` expression with something like (doesn't compile):

```hs
zipWith3 (\case
    (foo, bar, Just baz)  -> Right "hell yeah"
    (foo, bar, Nothing) -> Left "tough luck"
) ["foo1", "foo2"] ["bar1", "bar2"] [Just "baz1", Just "baz2"]
```

In the first (working) version, `case` receives a tuple, but in the (failing) LambdaCase version, it seems that `case` would receive the three arguments instead of a tuple. I don't know if this is possible to do something like that.

Comment: I have sometimes wished for a lambda-multi-case feature. It's a shame there isn't one; I guess the biggest issue is working out what syntax to use to differentiate lambda-single-case from lambda-multi-case without stealing another keyword. Perhaps ```\case/``` or ```\case\``` for the multi version or something.

Comment: Oh, and: you might like [`note`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors-2.3.0/docs/Control-Error-Util.html#v:note).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add [curry3](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=curry3) (for example, from `extra` package):

```hs
zipWith3 (curry3 $ \case
    (foo, bar, Just baz)  -> Right "hell yeah"
    (foo, bar, Nothing) -> Left "tough luck"
) ["foo1", "foo2"] ["bar1", "bar2"] [Just "baz1", Just "baz2"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, since the pattern is only on the final argument, is to bind the first two with a normal lambda and the last with a lambdacase:

```
zipWith3 (\foo bar -> \case
    Just baz -> Right "hell yeah"
    Nothing -> Left "tough luck"
) [] [] []
```

I personally find this more visually pleasing, but have no particular technical reason to prefer this or the `curry3` solution.

Comment: I like this one a lot, as it conveys the purpose of the pattern matching more clearly